# Convert string column to date-time in mongodb using SQL

Tags: sql, mongodb

I have json data loaded in mongodb table ALTMETRIC_2018 and I am using SQL to query (I don't know anything about mongo query language). The problem is that `citation.pubdate` column is of type String and I want to change it to type date using SQL. The usual SQL commands like "alter column" or functions won't work here.  Please guide me I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

SQL in MongoDB? I think you use a Mongo IDE that convert SQL to Mongo Language. Mongo don't support SQL.

Mongo don't have schemes tables. Don't have columns with a type. Each document (row) can be different.  The citiation.pubdate can be different in each document.

If you save the data as DateTime, mongo will save it as DateTime, you can't no change the database, only "the data".

UPDATE:

Create a script that find all data, change the date and save.

```
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(d) {
  var date = d.citation.pubdate;
  var asDate = new ISODate(date);


 db.collectionName.updateOne({_id: d._id}, { $set: { "citation.pubdate": asDate } });


});
```

Maybe you must change the date converter if you date is not a valid format.

Comment: yes i am using studio 3T IDE. how to change the data to date?